# yii2 doesnt set cookies when calling render method

Tags: php, cookies, layout, yii2, set

I try to set cookie with this action in a yii2 controller:

```
public function actionContact() {
$cookie = new Cookie([
            'name' => 'test_name',
            'value' => 'test_value'
        ]);
Yii::$app->getResponse()->getCookies()->add($cookie);
return $this->render('contact');
}
```

But it doesnt work like this. Meanwhile if I do it without rendering the contact view, it does work. It also works if I use

```
return $this->redirect('anothercontroller');
```

instead of

```
return $this->render('contact');
```

If I use it without layout ($this->layout = false) then it also works. 
Is the html header in the layout file overwriting the previous info?

The skeleton of the layout file is this:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Url;
//etc...

AppAsset::register($this);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/img/logo4.xcf" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart']});
            google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['gauge']});
            google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['geochart'],
    'mapsApiKey': 'AIzaSyDW77Ajhkkj0-c70o5lXawp89Sfj81TI' 
    });
     </script>
    <?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>
    <?php $this->head() ?>
</head> 
<body>
    <?php $this->beginBody() ?>  
        <?= $content ?>
    <?php $this->endBody() ?>
</body> 
</html>
<?php $this->endPage() ?>
```

Is there any workaround? 
Thanks for your time!

Comment: What is the content of the main layout file? Does is do anything out of the ordinary?

Comment: Hi Marteen! I edited my post with the info. Thanks!

Comment: You do know that cookie is available in the next request, not the one you are setting it with? Maybe that is why you think it does not work with `render`?

Comment: Hi Bizley! I am checking the cookie with the "EditThisCookie" chrome extension. I am not checking any subsequent requests.